# Correct way of displaying nested array object - issue with sorting an array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have got set of Web API 2.2 fetched data. It is stored in an Angular array of type object. That object has declared field for storing another array.

Simply, main object is of type Client, it has properties like name, surname, but also has a collection of contracts which are assigned to that client.

That's the class .ts:

```
export interface Client {
  Id: number;
  name: string;
  surname: string;
  Contracts: any;
}
```

I managed to display all the data in tables, get one user from table, but what I am struggling with is to sort this array of clients in the following way:

If I select/type - whatever - some contract property (lets say ContractId) I want to receive only Clients whose got at lest one contract with the ContractID.

Alright, but what doesn't seem to be intuitive for me is the following.

I access my clients array, declared as `clients: Array<Client> = [];`
Output in the console is clear, I see object, and all it's fields including contracts.

But when I try to access this.clients[i] (in a loop of course) or even this.clients[0].Contracts, I get undefined.

So far I've tried changing Contracts to ['Contracts'], or adding [0] before, but nothing seems to work.

Following code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.clients.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.clients[i]);
      console.log(this.clients[i].Contracts);
      for (var j = 0; j < this.clients[i].Contracts.length; j++) {
        console.log(this.clients[i].Contracts[j]);
      }

    }
```

generates output (undefined error):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in output log, you have `contracts` field, not `Contracts` (small `c`)

Answer (score 0):

Change Code Segment

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.clients.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.clients[i]);
      console.log(this.clients[i].Contracts);
      for (var j = 0; j < this.clients[i].Contracts.length; j++) {
        console.log(this.clients[i].Contracts[j]);
      }

    }
```

To

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.clients.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.clients[i]);
      console.log(this.clients[i].Contracts);
      for (var j = 0; j < this.clients[i].contracts.length; j++) {
        console.log(this.clients[i].contracts[j]);
      }

    }
```

it will be better u can use for-each loop

```
 for (let client of this.clients) {
      console.log(clients);
      console.log(client.contracts);
      for (let contact of client.contracts) {
          console.log(contact); 
     }
}
```

Hope this will helps ..!!